# Using EAGLContext with CIContext on MacOS

Tags: swift, swift3, core-image

I have a simple Swift command-line MacOS application and I'm struggling to set `EAGLContext`:

```
let openGLContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)
let context = CIContext(EAGLContext: openGLContext)
```

The above code gives me:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'EAGLContext'
```

no matter what modules I load:

```
import CoreImage
import OpenGL
import QuartzCore
import GLKit
```

Now the question is: does `CIContext` use OpenGL rendering by default?

When I initialize a new `CIContext` without any options:

```
let context = CIContext()
```

and set env variable `CI_PRINT_TREE` to `1` the console output gives me:

```
initial graph image_get_cgimage (opengl context 1 frame 1)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so it does process my filter in the GPU context, right?. Is there a way to explicitly set GPU rendering or is GPU a default context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer in the Apple docs available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html):

> **Rendering with an Automatic Context**
>
> If you don’t have constraints on how your app interoperates with other
>   graphics technologies, creating a Core Image context is simple: just
>   use the basic `init` or `initWithOptions:` initializer. When you do so,
>   Core Image automatically manages resources internally, **choosing the
>   appropriate or best available CPU or GPU rendering technology** based
>   on the current device and any options you specify.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cicontext)

There is a way to initialize `CIContext` on CPU or GPU explicitly

Also you can specify Metal or OpenGL

**Creating a Context for CPU-Based Rendering**

```
init(cgContext: CGContext, options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

> Creates a Core Image context from a Quartz context, using the
>   specified options.

**Creating a Context for GPU-Based Rendering with OpenGL:**

```
init(cglContext: CGLContextObj, pixelFormat: CGLPixelFormatObj?, colorSpace: CGColorSpace?, options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

> Creates a Core Image context from a CGL context, using the specified
>   options, color space, and pixel format object.

```
init(eaglContext: EAGLContext)
```

> Creates a Core Image context from an EAGL context.

```
init(eaglContext: EAGLContext, options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

> Creates a Core Image context from an EAGL context using the specified
>   options.

```
init?(forOfflineGPUAt: UInt32)
```

> Creates an OpenGL-based Core Image context using a GPU that is not
>   currently driving a display.

```
init?(forOfflineGPUAt: UInt32, colorSpace: CGColorSpace?, options: [String : Any]? = nil, sharedContext: CGLContextObj?)
```

> Creates an OpenGL-based Core Image context using a GPU that is not
>   currently driving a display, with the specified options.

**Creating a Context for GPU-Based Rendering with Metal**

```
init(mtlDevice: MTLDevice)
```

> Creates a Core Image context using the specified Metal device.

```
init(mtlDevice: MTLDevice, options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

> Creates a Core Image context using the specified Metal device and
>   options.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the docs. The question is still open: Why using an empty initializer `CIContext()` the image is processed in OpenGL context if I haven't explicitly specified that?

Comment: @Pono I thought this was the Question "so it does process my filter in the GPU context, right?. Is there a way to explicitly set GPU rendering or is GPU a default context?"

Comment: @Pono Well I suppose it sets it's default to GPU because all the "CI" stuff was built especially to enable GPU processing on images. I agree it doesn't clearly points so in Docs, However I am more interested in another Question of this kind "Why OpenGL and not Metal ?"

Comment: what benefits provides Metal over OpenGL in terms of performance?

Comment: @Pono Metal is advertised to be more efficient because it is GPU specific layer, that means it has less code bloat inside and can benefit of latest GPU optimizations (because it doesn't have to support all the old and/or non existent GPUs on Apple's platforms).

*TLDR* In my game using Metal I can draw twice as much animatable 3D Objects than in OpenGL, ofcourse it is specific example in my specific case -> but for me it works this way -> I think it tells something :)
**Also Apple are known for Poor OpenGL implementation** atleast in Macs

Comment: can you please point me to getting started guide for "humans"? Also, how different is Metal API from Open GL? In my case I'm interested in image processing (resizing, filtering, etc)

Comment: @Pono Are you familiar with OpenGL ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127158/discussion-between-pono-and-nsdawg).